# Lighttpd Server Problems: FCGI-related error

Tags: php, lighttpd

On Ubuntu 16 I have compiled PHP using the following config options:

```
./configure --enable-debug \
    --enable-maintainer-zts \
    --enable-pthreads \
    --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
    --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
    --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
    --enable-mbstring \
    --enable-cgi \
    --with-curl \
    --enable-soap \
    --enable-zip \
    --with-mcrypt \
    --with-kerberos \
    --with-zlib \
    --with-gettext \
    --enable-posix \
    --enable-sockets \
    --enable-pcntl \
    --with-pear \
    --with-sqlite3 \
    --enable-inline-optimization \
    --disable-rpath \
    --enable-sockets \
    --enable-sysvsem \
    --enable-sysvshm \
    --enable-mbregex \
    --enable-bcmath \
    --with-pcre-regex \
    --with-openssl \
    --enable-ftp \
    --with-imap \
    --with-imap-ssl \
    --with-mhash \
    --with-xmlrpc \
    --with-xsl \
    --enable-opcache
```

Compiled successfully!

Then I use

```
apt-get install lighttpd gamin
lighty-enable-mod fastcgi
lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php
service lighttpd force-reload
```

After rebooting I type

```
sudo service lighttpd status
```

It shows errors.
In *Lighttpd's* error log I have:

```
2016-06-23 03:14:55: (log.c.164) server started 
2016-06-23 03:15:02: (server.c.1558) server stopped by UID = 0 PID = 1 
2016-06-23 03:15:03: (log.c.164) server started 
2016-06-23 03:15:03: (mod_fastcgi.c.1112) the fastcgi-backend /usr/bin/php-cgi failed to start: 
2016-06-23 03:15:03: (mod_fastcgi.c.1116) child exited with status 2 /usr/bin/php-cgi 
2016-06-23 03:15:03: (mod_fastcgi.c.1119) If you're trying to run your app as a FastCGI backend, make sure you're using the FastCGI-enabled version.
If this is PHP on Gentoo, add 'fastcgi' to the USE flags. 
2016-06-23 03:15:03: (mod_fastcgi.c.1406) [ERROR]: spawning fcgi failed. 
2016-06-23 03:15:03: (server.c.1022) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down.
```

How to deal with this problem?
I used to do the same thing with Ubuntu 12.x/14.x and Lighttpd worked OK

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that /usr/bin/php-cgi exist (and is the version that you built, if that is what you want), and then execute '/usr/bin/php-cgi your-script-here' manually, the same as if lighttpd were going to execute it.  Then you should see why your script is failing.